# Validate webhook request using HMAC security with REST API

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I am using DocusSign connect webhook service and want to use HMAC Security to validate the request. To do this I have followed the instructions mentioned in
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac  that is:

1. On our account on DocuSign, I have set for Connect the Include HMAC Signature and created a Connect Authentication Key.
2. Received the Connect message from Docusign connect containing the header with the data hashed with the application’s defined HMAC keys.
3. But facing the issue in 3rd step i.e. validating the HMAC signature using below code -

```
// x-docusign-signature headers

String headerSign = request.getHeader("X-DocuSign-Signature-1");
String secret = "....";

-------
public static boolean HashIsValid(String secret, String payload,
       String headerSign)
       throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
           UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String computedHash = ComputeHash(secret, payload);
        boolean isEqual = 
            MessageDigest.isEqual(computedHash.getBytes("UTF-8"), 
            headerSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return isEqual;
}
------


public static String ComputeHash(String secret, String payload)
            throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        String digest = "HmacSHA256";
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(digest);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), digest));
        String base64Hash = new String(
            Base64.getEncoder().encode(mac.doFinal(payload.getBytes())));
        return base64Hash;
}
```

But it always returns false.

Anyone who has any idea why my hash code is different from the one received from DocuSign?

Answer (score 1):

Either your comparison test is wrong or your payload variable is including too much or too little.

To test your comparison, print out `computedHash` and `headerSign`.

To test your `payload` value, print it out and check that it is the entire body of the POST request to your listener (your server).

Also check that you have exactly one `X-DocuSign-Signature` header. One way is to confirm that there is no value for header `X-DocuSign-Signature-2`

I've filed internal bug report DEVDOCS-4874 since the [Java example](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/validate/) has a bug.